Yup conditional object concat
I need to concat proper object to base one when method is "once" or "shedule". CalendarTimeAndPlaceSchema and CalendarTimeAndPlaceScheduleSchema are objects.
On elements in form it shows me an error:
Type "date" is not assignable to type "name" | "desc" | "method"
const CalendarDataSchema = object({
  name: string().trim().required("Nazwa jesy wymagana"),
  desc: string().optional(),
  method: string()
    .oneOf(["once", "schedule"])
    .required("Metoda jest wymagana")
    .default("once"),
}) // here concat proper object schema
  .when("method", {
    is: "once",
    then: (schema) => schema.concat(CalendarTimeAndPlaceSchema),
    otherwise: (schema) => schema.concat(CalendarTimeAndPlaceScheduleSchema),
  })


I tried making when() on each element and add to it proper options but it seams to be a really huge stack of code.

Can you make a reproducible example of what you have in playcode.io/react or codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-new?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
